# Python: Multiple Graphs For Loop

Tags: python, loops, graph

My data set has 5 ClientIDs, I would like to produce a graph for each ClientID

I have been able to iterate through my key and create five graphs however, they are including all the data and not just that of the client ID

```
# group by "X" column
clients = dfT1.groupby('ClientID')
 
# extract keys from groups
keys = clients.groups.keys()

for i in keys:
    dfT1[:].plot(x='Dates', y=['DWLTActual', 'Weight'], figsize=(10,5), grid=True)
    plt.show()
```

Output

[Example of the 5 graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj1yZ.jpg)

Expected Output

[Example of one of the client graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV7tT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check it like this. I executed with sample data locally on my computer and it worked.

You need to filter the client data first before plotting.

```
clients = dfT1.groupby('ClientID')

# Extract keys from groups
keys = clients.groups.keys()


for client_id in keys:
    # Filter data for the current client ID
    client_data = clients.get_group(client_id)

    # Plot the filtered data
    client_data.plot(x='Dates', y=['DWLTActual', 'Weight'], figsize=(10, 5), grid=True)

    # Set the title of the graph as the ClientID
    plt.title('ClientID: {}'.format(client_id))

    # Show the plot
    plt.show()
```